# Registering Key_acute event does not work on first key press

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using Qt 5 (PyQt5 to be specific) and want to check for a keypress.

The problem I have, is the `Qt::Key_acute` event not registering on first button press.

I use the german keyboard layout<sup>[1]</sup>, maybe this is a problem I don't know, but I still want to to work nonetheless, as I know it works in other programs (non-Qt).

When pressing the `Key_acute` key (in the linked image, the one left to the backspace key), nothing happens on the first press, but when I press it again I get two events printed to console: `180` and `0` (180 = 0x0b4 = Key_acute).

How do I capture the first keypress event for this key?

Example PyQt5 program:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, argv):
        super().__init__()

        self.box = QLabel(self)
        self.show()


    def keyPressEvent(self, ev):
        print(ev.key())
        self.box.setText(str(ev.key()))
        self.box.adjustSize()

        super().keyPressEvent(ev)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sup>[1]</sup> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/KB_Germany.svg

Comment: If you write in a QLineEdit and press that key only once is something written in the QLineEdit?

Comment: @eyllanesc No. But it's like this in for example Notepad too, since the `´ usually wait for, for example, an "a", to make á. But there has to be a way to register the first press nonetheless. At least a different program I know of, does this without problems.

Answer (score 0):

The [ ´ ] key in most keyboards is a "[dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)", a special kind of key that waits for the following to "compose" the actual character.

As far as I know, you can only get those keys as a release event, not a press event.

When *some* dead keys are pressed twice, they are not sent as key press/release events, but you they can be intercepted with [`event()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#event) as `QEvent.InputMethod` types.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

keyNameFromValue = {}
keyNameFromString = {}
for k, v in vars(Qt).items():
    if isinstance(v, Qt.Key):
        keyNameFromValue[v] = k
        keyNameFromString[QKeySequence(v).toString()] = k


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, argv):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.box = QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.box)
        self.show()

    def event(self, ev):
        if ev.type() == QEvent.InputMethod:
            s = ev.commitString()
            if s:
                self.box.setText('InputMethod > {}: {}'.format(
                     keyNameFromString.get(s, '(Unknown)'), s))
                self.box.adjustSize()
        return super().event(ev)

    def keyPressEvent(self, ev):
        if not ev.isAutoRepeat():
            self.box.setText('KeyPress > {}: {}'.format(
                keyNameFromValue.get(ev.key()), ev.text()))
            self.box.adjustSize()
        super().keyPressEvent(ev)

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, ev):
        if not ev.isAutoRepeat():
            self.box.setText('KeyRelease > {}: {}'.format(
                keyNameFromValue.get(ev.key()), ev.text()))
            self.box.adjustSize()
        super().keyReleaseEvent(ev)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this case, the first time the [ ´ ] key is pressed the result is `Key_Dead_Acute` (which is not directly printable), and the second time it's `Key_acute`.

You could create your own dict-based mapping for dead keys (there's less than 50 of them) if you need to show how the printable dead key should appear as a string.
Unfortunately there's no programmatical way to do so, as their string conversion differs even for the "same" character and there is no actual correlation between `Qt.Key_Dead_*` and `Qt.Key_*` names or values: for instance, while `Qt.Key_Dead_Acute` corresponds to `Qt.Key_acute`, `Qt.Key_Dead_Grave` becomes `Qt.Key_QuoteLeft`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "not directly printable"? Do you mean the label won't show anything? At least this I can confirm, no "Key_Dead_Acute" ever shows up. Interestingly, two other programs that work fine with detecting those keys (MPC-HC and PotPlayer) detect it as `]` (and they also detect other keys in this region as completely different to QWERTZ (not even matching US layout)). PyCharm can detect it as `dead_acute`. So I guess it's just a Qt issue not being able to catch this event, as just print("x") won't to anything in either of the event functions in your example.

Comment: @user136036 Dead keys are almost the same as modifier keys: you can't "print" a shift key, and the ´ dead key acts as some sort of alternate shift; the only difference is that normal modifiers require a concurrent press, dead keys a consecutive one. When you press "shift+a" the OS "modifies" the behavior of the key "a" and makes it "A", when you press ´ the same happens making it "á". Remember that, from a low level point of view, key events are just scancodes sent from the keyboard, it's up to the OS "translate" them and the programs to "transform" them to string representation if required.

Comment: Each framework can provide different levels of "detection" for the programmer, and it also depends from the OS API. Also consider that Qt has to maintain a common cross platform layer, which might become slightly inconsistent from OS to OS or has some kind of limitation to keep compatibility. Then, it's possible that for some reason Qt just doesn't/can't provide an event for the ` key press (it could be caught, though, by installing a QAbstractNativeEventFilter on the app), but I don't think of it as an actual issue.